# sorting in linechart along with bar chart in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe

```
    A   B           C
3   4   0.425744    62244
2   3   0.351339    61479
1   2   0.221772    62677
0   1   0.204175    63181
```

using field `C` for `barplot` and `B` in `lineplot`,

```
#code of plot 
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(6,4))
sns.lineplot(data = af['B'], marker='o', ax=ax1,)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.barplot(data = af, x='A',y="C" , alpha=0.5, ax=ax2)
```

[image]

I want to sort the value according to the line charts. In our case the sequence should be 4-3-2-1.

Comment: see if resetting the index on `af` makes a difference?

Comment: @Riley resetting the index , only line graph is getting changed , sequence of x axis is still same

Comment: Maybe converting `A` to strings or categoricals could help.  Alternatively (as a hack) multiply `A` by -1 so it naturally orders it the way you want, then change the x-axis labels to remove negative signs.

Comment: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions-(FAQs)#why-cant-i-draw-a-line-over-a-barboxstripviolin-plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

1. Convert `A` to `str`:

   ```
   af['A'] = af['A'].astype(str)
   ```
2. Instead of `data=af['B']`, use `af` as the `data` source with `x='A'`:

   ```
   sns.lineplot(data=af, x='A', y='B', marker='o', ax=ax1)
   ```

Code and output:

```
af['A'] = af['A'].astype(str)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(6,4))
sns.lineplot(data=af, x='A', y='B', marker='o', ax=ax1)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.barplot(data=af, x='A', y='C', alpha=0.5, ax=ax2)
```

[image]